# Search Query Parameter

Tags: laravel, search, routes

I want to search email which contains '+' in it. for example 
something like this `myemail.subdomain+1@domain.com`.

URL - `https://example.com?searchKey=myemail.subdomain+1@`

I am using Laravel, this parameter is fetched from route using
`$request->get('searchKey');`
but it's converting '+' to ' ' , 
as a result i am getting 
searchKey as `myemail.subdomain 1@`

which leads to improper result.
Any help?

Comment: Why you are not making it just `str_replace(' ', '+', $request->input('searchKey'))`

Answer (score 2):

PHP assumes that `+` from GET request is a space. Right encoded plus symbol is `%2B`.
You have to just prepare string from request to save plus symbol:

`$searchKey= urlencode(request()->get('searchKey'));`

In your case you'll get `@` as `%40`. Then you can replace plus with correct code and decode it. **But then be careful with usual spaces!**

```php
$searchKey = urlencode(request()->get('searchKey'));
$searchKey = urldecode(str_replace('+', '%2B', $searchKey));
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php

P.S. I suppose it is not the best soulution, but it should work.

P.P.S. Or, if you can prepare plus as a `%2B` before it will be at search parameter, do it

Comment: but this will convert ```@``` to ```%40```. effectively my query string would be ```myemail.subdomain+1%40```